# If $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ has cardinality $\kappa$, then some $A_i$ has cardinality $\kappa$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Is the following claim true?

> If $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ has cardinality $\kappa$, then some $A_i$ has cardinality $\kappa$. Here $\kappa$ is uncountable.

I'm interested in the particular case $\kappa=c:=|\mathbb{R}|$. In other words, if each $A_i$ has cardinality strictly less than $\kappa$, can we deduce that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i$ has cardinality less than $\kappa$?

I know very little cardinal arithmetic beyond the usual rules for sums and products. But I came across this in an analysis text, so I wonder whether it's true.

Comment: What text was this  **#*!%** in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example:

$$\left| \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \omega_i \right| = \omega_\omega$$

---

We have:

$$\kappa = \left| \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right| \le \omega \cdot \sup_{i=1..\infty} |A_i| = \sup_{i=1..\infty} |A_i|$$

So in order to conclude that $\kappa = |A_i|$ for some $i$, we need $\operatorname{cof}(\kappa) = \omega$, otherwise there are coutner-examples. For $\kappa = \mathfrak c$ though, you are lucky, since $\operatorname{cof}(\mathfrak c) > \omega$, so you can always conclude that $\kappa = |A_i|$ for some $i$.

---

Specializing on the case $\kappa = \mathfrak c$:

Let $|A_i| < \mathfrak c$ for all $i$. By Konig's lemma:
$$\left| \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \right| < \left| \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathfrak c \right| = \mathfrak c^\omega = 2^{\omega \cdot \omega} = 2^\omega = \mathfrak c$$

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you please elaborate on why this is true for $c$? I don't understand your notation cof and all that.. (I'm practically blind about set theory)

Comment: The last part is not exactly true in ZF, it is consistent that the reals are countable union of countable sets. In ZFC it is true(the proof that $\mbox{cof}(2^λ)>λ$ require choice)

Comment: @Colescu I've included some explanation

Comment: It might be better to wriite $\aleph_i$ instead of $\omega_i$, just to make sure we''re using _cardinal_ operations. (For example: $\omega=\aleph_0$; one thinks of $\omega$ as an ordinal annd $\aleph_0$ as a cardinal. So, with cardinal multiplication, $\aleph_0\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. But if the notation $\omega\omega$ is interppreted as an _ordinal_ product then $\omega\omega\ne\omega$.)